# Recreate channel for orderer from peer channel information

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

v1.4.1

I have a network with 3 orderers, this 3 orderers don't know why started to say that the service was unavailable, giving 503 for new transactions.Here are some of the logs:

```
2020-09-15 10:10:41.235 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.puller] fetchLastBlockSeq -> INFO 27575 Skipping pulling from <ip>:7050: minimum requested sequence is 3522 but <ip>:7050 is at sequence 3521
2020-09-15 10:10:41.235 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.puller] func1 -> WARN 27576 Received error of type 'minimum requested sequence is 3522 but <ip>7050 is at sequence 3521' from <ip>:7050
2020-09-15 10:10:41.235 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 27577 transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-09-15 10:10:41.235 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.puller] fetchLastBlockSeq -> INFO 27578 Skipping pulling from <ip2>:7050: minimum requested sequence is 3522 but <ip2>:7050 is at sequence 3521
2020-09-15 10:10:41.235 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.puller] func1 -> WARN 27579 Received error of type 'minimum requested sequence is 3522 but <ip2>:7050 is at sequence 3521' from <ip2>:7050
2020-09-15 10:10:41.235 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.puller] connectToSomeEndpoint -> WARN 2757a Could not connect to any endpoint of [<itself>:7050 <ip>:7050 <ip3>:7050]
```

I do not understand what is going on, also it can not connect to itself, see last command line.

Can someone explain me whats going on?

Also, can I recreate the data for the orderers from the peer data?

Edit1:

The peer on the logs says the following:

```
[blocksProvider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 1996cbb [channelname] Got error &{NOT_FOUND}
```

Also the orderer says the following

```
[common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> ERRO 3201e [channel: channel] Error reading from channel, cause was: NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: When the log say "minimum requested version is" I think it has to do with the current version of the world state , from what I understand your orderer is not up to date with the world state , and so cannot communicate/is blocked. Can you verify that every peer can communicate on the Port 7051 ? And from your edit , can you verify your configtx to look from an error with the channel ? (like a type in the name of the channel , or a peer that is not in the right channel).

Comment: Hey @Popopame the channel worked fine until now, the communication between the peers and the orderers is working just with one, the other 2 are not working it says service unavailable. Nothing has changed on the configtx. How can I recover the 2 orderers?

Comment: First you need to restablish connection with all the orderer nodes (or a least juste one) , after that , if you are using raft , the orderer should agre on a sequence. Now for reestablishing the communication there is a problem with the channel , wich actions did you took before the error occured ?

Comment: Thanks @Popomame A new transaction was set, before this, everything was going as usual and communication between orderers was good. Also I think that the problem came because the system disk didn't have space left (very little), although all the fabric related things are on an attached disk. To reestablish the connection what would be the approach in this case? I need at least one orderer to have 2 of them connected.

Comment: Is the disk problem resolved ? Some of the file hyperledger use for functioning are stored on disk , that could explain the channel error. For me , the step would be to explore system level error on your network (see if every component of the network function correctly , does not return error , have access to all channel artifacts, have enough disk space). Then you need to explore this channel error , if they are not on the same channel , all the nodes cannot communicates. Check if the channel still and if it does not return error. Use the peer channel info to do so , Godspeed !

Comment: How many organizations with peers do you have? Can you fetch the config block or the latest block for every one? Which is the result of the discovery form each one?

Comment: Hey @Urko we only have 1 organization. I can get the config block of the peers. Result of the discovery? What do you mean?

Comment: @Bentipe After reading the following answer, I understarn that you have solved your issue? Sure?

Comment: Hey @Urko yes, as its a test network I just recreated everything, I was trying to understand what were my options here if this happened again. Thanks a lot :). If you have any idea of how to approach this, please do it.

Comment: Hey @Bentipe. Yeah, I have some ideas, but as I understand, you have removed the enviroment that was taking you to that issue, so, we can not get the configuration an additiona info. However, it seems really unusual that the peers did not restore from orderers. As you mentioned, it seems to be something related to the disk and volumes of your docker containers but I can say anythim more. I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem @Urko thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the disk problem resolved ?
Some of the files hyperledger use for functioning are stored on disk , that could explain the channel error.
For me , the step would be to explore system level errors on the participants of your network (see if every components of the network function correctly , does not return error , have access to all channel artifacts, have enough disk space, ect...).
Then you need to explore this channel error , if they are not on the same channel , all the nodes cannot communicates. Check if the channel still and if it does not return error. Use the peer channel info to do so: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerchannel.html
Is this  a test/learning env or a production network?
Godspeed !

Comment: Thanks popopame, fortunately is a test network, if this happens on production... o my. Yes, disk problem is solved, this test channel we did not have monitored (now yes). I decided to recreated in the end, as it was needed to test some things, but, thanks a lot for your help. I am trying to assess what were my options in this situation.

Comment: That's for me the biggest issue with Hyperledger Fabric ATM , debugging theses kind of bugs is really difficult. But in a Production network and with the right experience , you can debug almost everything in Fabric , because you will setup a better monitoring (and not have the wall of text that is the ouput of docker compose) , good policies , backups, ect... Happy Learning !